# Can't install deluge on Debian sid

Tags: debian, apt, python, dependencies, libraries

Everytime I try to install Deluge on my system it throws this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-libtorrent : Depends: python3 (< 3.9) but 3.9.0-3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So anyone know a solution to install deluge on Debian sid. Deluge was working before I updated my system now it can't even install.

Answer (score 0):

`python3-libtorrent` is [currently broken in sid](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=967169), and as a result [failed to build](https://buildd.debian.org/status/package.php?p=libtorrent-rasterbar) in the transition to Python 3.9. As a result, it is no longer installable, which is fine for unstable.

The solution is to fix the bugs in `python3-libtorrent` — after all, unstable is the development version of Debian, and its intended use is to develop the next release of Debian (which is taking form in the testing suite). There is [an updated version](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/libtorrent-rasterbar/) ready in the package’s git repository, so you could try building that.

Comment: yup, sorry for long response. This was the case, I have to build libtorrent from github for deluge to work. But for some reason everytime I update my system libtorrent get reset back so I have to rebuild it again. I just used transmission instead, it doesn't seams to relay on lib-torrent to work.